# Всем привет. Решил помочь матери и написать программу, типа 1с, но не знаю с чего начать. Может есть у кого советы?

Tags: java, база-данных, ооп

Изучают java. Сама программа думаю будет простая, единственному юзеру. Связанная с сырьем и после приходит на кухню и делается калькуляционная карта на будку хлеба и тд. И после посчитать сколько вышло продукции и остаток на складе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам сейчас занимаюсь подобным. Первое что советую сделать, хорошо обсудить все требования к ПО. Изучи БД, MySQL например. Потом тебе нужен будет UI. Для UI на Java я использую JavaFX. Но посмотри сам, не один только JavaFX используется для UI. Ну а дальше по чучуть: добавил форму ввода, сохранил в базу, написал логику. Заведи тетрадь/файл записывай задачи, начинай их поэтапно реализовывать. Постепенно будут возникать вопросы, ищи ответы в google/stackoverflow. Будешь задавать тут вопросы, посмотри предварительно, чаще всего ответы уже есть. Если нет, старайся дать как можно больше информации, но при этом лаконично излагай.

P.S. Я не знаю твой уровень знаний, но на всякий случай посоветую использовать ООП. Когда то я взялся писать desctop приложение, вся логика была в 2-4 классах, огромная масса кода, дублирование кода и т.д. Это может здорово затормозить разработку и отбить желание. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за совет)